# ES6 Equivalent of method.invoke for proxy objects in spider monkey?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Spidermonkey has the `invoke` handler for Proxy objects. I can do stuff like:

```
let o = { foo () {} };
let x = Proxy(o, { invoke: function () { console.log('method invoked!'); } });
x.foo(); // logs 'method invoked'
```

Is there an ES6 equivalent for this? Can't find it in spec.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: No.

---

Aha! Another proposer for the `invoke` trap :) This has a fair amount of history with the ES6 spec. The last time a war ensued over this was at [this ESDiscuss thread](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es6-proxy-function-call-trap) which basically sums up the feelings of the TC overall for why `invoke` didn't make it to the ES6 spec. tl;dr for that thread is: `handler.invoked === handler.get + handler.call`, so best to to not add another trap which breaks equivalence.

So a longer answer for this would be to just use `handler.get` and `handler.call` together.

```
// pseudo code for handler object
handler = {
    ...
    get (key, o) {
        if (Reflect.get(o, key) === 'function') {
            return handler.invoke(key, o);
        }
        ...
    },
    invoke (key, o) {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

This obviously won't work if the method is not already defined, so if you want to catch `o.arbitraryFuncCall()`, there isn't a way really :(

Comment: So they took away our __noSuchMethod__ and gave us.... nothing?? Catching `o.arbitraryFuncCall()` is *exactly* what I want to do.